# Minimize the rank of a matrix with some entries known

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, coding-theory, matrix-rank, computational-algebra

Let $m,n$ be two positive integers, with $m\geq n$. Suppose we have $m$ sets $A_1,\ldots, A_m\subseteq [n]$, with
$|A_i|=d_i$. Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field of size $q$.

Let $D$ be the set defined as

$$ D:=\left\{(i,j)\in [m]\times[n] \,|\, j \in A_i\right\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^m \{i\}\times A_i$$
We denote by $x=(x_{ij})_{(i,j)\notin D}$ and by $y=(y_{ij})_{(i,j)\in D}$.

Define the $m \times n$ matrix $B(x,y)$ as the matrix whose entries are given by

$$b_{ij}=\begin{cases}
   x_{ij} & \mbox{ if } (i,j)\notin D \\
   y_{ij} & \mbox{ if } (i,j)\in D
  \end{cases}
$$

I would like to find conditions on the following value

$$N:=\max_{\alpha=(\alpha_{ij})_{(i,j)\in D}} \min_{\beta=(\beta_{ij})_{(i,j)\in D}} \{rank(B(\alpha,\beta))|\alpha_{ij},\beta_{ij}\in \mathbb F\}.$$

**Conjecture:** $N$ is equal to the maximum integer $k$ such that there exist $P$ and $Q$ with 
$$PB(x,y)Q=\left[
 \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
x_{i_1j_1} &  & ? & \\
    \vdots          & \ddots & & &?\\
  x_{i_kj_1} & \ldots  & x_{i_kj_k}  & \\
                      \hline \\
       &   ?     & &  & ?        \\                    
 \end{array}\right] $$

**Partial proof**: It is trivial to show that $N\leq k$. In fact by choosing $\alpha_{i_lj_l}=1$ for $l=1,\ldots,k$ and $\alpha_{i_lj_r}=0$ for $r<l$, we obtain a $k\times k$ submatrix whose determinant is $1$.

---

Some considerations: Actually I want to prove that, if there not exist such permutation matrices for some integer $k'$, then the ideal 
$$I_{k'}:=(\Delta_{I,J}(\alpha,y)|I\subseteq[m], J\subseteq [m], |I|=|J|=k')\subseteq\mathbb F[y],$$
is such that 
$$\mathcal V_{\mathbb F}(I_{k'})=\emptyset.$$
I am quite sure that for such ideal, (since it's generated by polynomials whose degrees in each variable is at most $1$) we have
$$\mathcal V_{\mathbb F}(I_{k'})=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow \mathcal V_{\bar{\mathbb F}}(I_{k'})=\emptyset.$$

So, here my list of questions:

1. Is this consideration about the algebraic sets true (in this case)?
2. Is my conjecture true? If not, could someone help me to find a counterexample?
3. Does my conjecture depend on the field size?
4. If the conjecture is not true could it become true with some of the following simplifications

a) $d_i=d$ for every $i=1,\ldots, m$;

b) $m=n$;

c) $\alpha_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ and $$\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{ij}=1$$ for every $i=1,\ldots,m$.

In particular I'm really interested in the simplifcatons $a)$ and $c)$.

Thank you in advance,
Alessandro